# .log file for Karma js unit testing

Tags: angularjs, logging, jasmine, karma-runner

I am making some js unit testing with Karma + Jasmine + ng-scenario

and I am trying to find a way to tell my karma to make a text .log file to save my results and/or errors. 
in case my tests are too long and some errors go out of the console.

anyone had similar need?

Comment: Does `karma run > tests.log` work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as @gustavohenke suggested

```
karma start > tests.log
```

or

```
karma run > tests.log
```

works and creates a log file.

Comment: Any idea how you can do this using gulp?