# Karma - unit test logging possible?

Tags: karma-runner

Is there a way to add text to unit tests (Jasmine or Mocha) run in Karma - maybe with a console.log - and be able to output it?  I understand using result.description (for example) in a reporter, but I don't know of any result.x that I can fill in from the test.  I'm not sure, but I think the log4js in Karma cannot be used from the test, as the test runs in the browser and the log4js is on the server?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268462/log-file-for-karma-js-unit-testing (for anyone else searching for answers on this)